# OpenX: Add custom fields for image banners (e.g. background color)

Tags: php, openx

What is the easiest way to add custom fields for image banners without creating a separate plugin for a new banner type?

If plugin is the only option — where can i find info about how to do it?

(I am studying the OpenX video plugin but it includes a plethora of features that i don't need, thus making it rather complex.)

Answer (score 1):

I understand the need to find "out of the box" solutions, but I would only do that if I had no other option.

If you are just wanting to have basic banners that will navigate to selected ad location, you can make your own up loader form. You can find many examples to help you.

Info to be collected can be anything you require such as with the image selection box, image dimensions, BG colour, URL link, ALT text, banner type, banner location and so on.

If you are monetising them, you can count the clicks.

A simple way would be to bounce your ad to a blank page momentarily to register your info in your Database before redirecting to the actual page.

Without knowing what scale or implementation you require, It is hard for people to target the right reply to your question.

I would say to use a given ad administrator a go, then all you need to do is paste the code into your site.

I personally use Google AdSense on my site, but there are others.

Comment: Does "ad administrator" allow for the extra features i'm looking for?

Comment: @Ernests Karlsons   

As I have only used "Google AdSense" I can only give it from that view.  

With Google AdSense, you create your ad's as in the type, size and dimensions. Such as 300 x 300 box or a skyscraper. 
Then you get the embed code which you will paste into your page where you wish the ad to be. All tracking and stuff is done for you and you can see the page hits and link hits and fine tune your ad's in your Google DashBoard page.